# Jquery Isotope: making horizontal Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I am trying to build a horizontal version of JQuery Masonry using JQuery Isotope. I want my result to look something like this:

[Layout-modes](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/layout-modes.html) (CLICK THE masonryHorizontal OPTION).

As per the sites instructions: 
[Masonry Horizontal](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/layout-modes.html#masonryhorizontal)
 my script looks like:

```
$('#isotopecontainer').isotope({
        itemSelector : '.item',
        masonry : {
          columnWidth : 270
        }
 });
```

However, 2 things are happening:

1) when the page loads the height of the `#isotopecontainer` div is set at 60px so you only see the tops of the `.item` divs.

2) if you resize the browser the `#isotopecontainer` div expands but the `.item` divs do not line up like the example.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction at all? My demo site is [here](http://clarkeconstructions.com.au/newsite/).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're demo site is working in Firefox.

Although, you're right, in Chrome it's not. The problem is fairly simple. **You need to set width and height attributes** on your images. Or else, Chrome load them as 0px height (which made container with default height of line-height value) until they get the file. Firefox isn't acting this way and waits for knowing the images size before creating the layout.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks, you are correct but the annoying thing is it breaks the plugin - images dont space out correctly

Comment: Unfortunately, no-one can know the size of the images before they're loaded. And unfortunately, chrome will start laying out your page before. So, you setup the size manually, or you call relayout method on isotope each time an image load (onload event)...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add layoutMode: 'masonryHorizontal' or else it won't work. Like this:

```
$('#isotopecontainer').isotope({
    itemSelector : '.item',
    layoutMode: 'masonryHorizontal',
    masonry : {
      columnWidth : 270
    }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

`#isotophecontainer` has `overflow: hidden`.  Removing this shows all of the images for me in Chrome.